# Using thread annotation not being inspected as expected

Tags: android, android-studio, annotations, metadata

I want to notify the developer that a method is required to be in the main thread so i wrote to following code :

```
  @MainThread
    public void showToast(@NonNull String text) {
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

than i wrote :

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showToast("");
        }
    }).start();
```

and the compiler not marking this as an error unlike `@StringRes` and others annotations that i used .

any idea why ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Supply your own annotations for thread inference**

The lint inspection (aptly named "WrongThread") cannot infer the thread that is calling the `showToast` method unless you supply annotations that mark a method as one of `@WorkerThread` etc.

Take your original code and add the `@WorkerThread` annotation to the `run` method:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    @WorkerThread
    public void run() {
        showToast("");
    }
}).start();
```

and it will correctly generate the lint inspection warning as below:

[image: lint inspection warning]

**Special case for `AsyncTask`**

`AsyncTask` has its methods marked with the correct thread annotations ([link to source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java)):

```
@WorkerThread
protected abstract Result doInBackground(Params... params);
```

you will get the warning for free if you happen to use an `AsyncTask` like in the following example:

```
new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        showToast(""); //warning here: method showToast must be called from the main thread
                       //currently inferred thread is worker
        return "";
    }
```

For other async patterns you will have to add your own `@WorkerThread` or other annotations.

The complete list of different threads is [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#thread-annotations):

```
@MainThread
@UiThread
@WorkerThread
@BinderThread
@AnyThread
```

Comment: I don't see any warnings at all when using Thread annotations. Do we have to change some settings on Android studio.

Comment: @UbaierBhat it should be enabled by default but you can check your Android Studio inspection settings for the "Wrong Thread" inspection